# How to delete scheme when deleting electron app on Mac

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am currently working on an electron project.

I have one question.

Our app uses a custom scheme,

Is there a way to automatically delete a scheme when deleting an app on a Mac?

Comment: What is "a custom scheme"?

Comment: https://help.contrast.co/hc/en-us/articles/200865293-URL-Scheme-Intro-for-App-Developers